# a sql query from oracle table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have only one column `roll number` in my oracle table. Lots of data are there in one column.

```
   roll number  

  -------------

      1 
      2
      3
      4
      5
      .
      .
      .
```

When i want to delete some roll numbers out of this table then i am writing:

```
delete from table name where roll number='2'; // 1 row deleted.
```

if i want to delete `5` from table then

```
delete from table name where roll number='5'; // 1 row deleted.
```

Similarly when i want to delete 100 records like this then i have to replace `roll number` field and it is quite time taking.
Is there any quick method how can i delete selective rows from the table?

Comment: you can use OR in your delete statement. Can you explain what really you want to achieve?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the ids to delete are consecutive you could use `BETWEEN`:

```
DELETE FROM your_table WHERE roll_number BETWEEN 5 AND 104
```

If not, you could use `IN`:

```
DELETE FROM your_table WHERE roll_number IN (5, 9, 110, ... )
```

Comment: +1. I'd lose the quotes if these are really numbers (I know the original question has them, too, but if the data really is in a text column, BETWEEN won't work so well).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list of number from another query and put it in a IN condition, so for example :

```
delete from table name where roll number IN (select roll number from table WHERE somecondition);
```

Comment: +1 but your example is a bit strange. You could just do `DELETE FROM table WHERE somecondition` instead.

Comment: Yes but maybe he could get the interested ids from another table, is only an example, i don't know the relations of the entire database ...

Answer (score 0):

If u already know the range u can use **Between** else if u know the total numbers to be deleted then u can use **IN** like....

```
delete from table where roll number BETWEEN ....;
```